# document.obj.write() ..is it possible?

Tags: javascript, onclick, onchange, document.write

what i wanted to do is when i clicked on a checkbox it will automatically appear on a certain part of the page. i tried to give a checkbox an **onclick='displayit()'/oncchange='displayit()'** where **displayit()** is:

```
function displayit(obj){
document.divnam.write(obj.value);
}
```

the **divnam** is the name of the division where i wanted the text to appear..isnt it possible?i also tried removing the **divnam** and putting the function itself in the division

```
<div name='divnam' ><script>
function displayit(obj){document.write(obj.value);}
</script></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an `id` on the `div` element instead of `name` so that you can easily access it. You use the `innerHTML` property to set the contents of the element:

```
function displayit(obj){
  document.getElementById('divnam').innerHTML = obj.value;
}
```

Putting the script inside the element would only work if you run the script while the page is loading. Declaring a function inside the element has no effect, it doesn't matter where in the page the function is declared.

Comment: ok yay thanks very much :) i forgot about innerHTML. what about i wanted to change the content of <b></b> elements..i should use jquery right? $(b)?

Comment: what about appending another text? like for example it already show the value then when i clicked on another checkbox i wanted the value to be appended to it..like making a list or something.

Comment: @kapitanluffy: If you want to add several texts to an element, you should add them as child elements, for example `span` elements. Create an element using `document.createElement('SPAN')`, put the text in that element, and use the `appendChild` method to add it to the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` only works while the page is initially loading. What you want to do now is to put some data in some part of the page, say a div with `id="target"`:

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

And the javascript part:

```
<script>
function displayit(obj){
  document.getElementById('target').innerHTML=obj.value;
}
</script>
```